# Running mstest tests in c++ in 64 bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mstest

I'm doing unit test of a library using 64 bits libraries (cuda SDK among others).
I'm trying to have a deeper diagnose with `cuda-memcheck`, therefore I'm running tests on the command line.

```
mstest.exe /testcontainer:CubicBSplinesTests.dll /test:RGBSliceDoubleConvert
```

It fails since it will try to run in 32 bits. I was recommanded to use "Any CPU" but there is no such thing in a c++ project. How can I make the test run in 64 bits in those conditions ?

> Unable to load the test container 'CubicBSplinesTests.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies. If you build your test project assembly as a 64 bit
>   assembly, it cannot be loaded. When you build your test project
>   assembly, select "Any CPU" for the platform. To run your tests in 64
>   bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you must change your test settings in
>   the Hosts tab to run your tests in a 32 bit process. Error details:
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///project_path\x64\Debug\CubicBSplinesTests.dll' or one
>   of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command is:

```
vstest.console.exe CubicBSplinesTests.dll --tests:RGBSliceDoubleConvert
```

After adding to path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow`

`mstest.exe` is for .net testing, not native c/c++ testing.